# Automated Coverage Testing C Program using gcovr Linux with perl

Tags: c, linux, perl, gcov, gcovr

I want to test 2 C programs to check it's coverage (line coverage and branch coverage).

I am using gcovr in linux system.

To do this, I have written a Perl Script that will call  `gcc` compiler  and read input from the file, then gives test for the coverage of C program.

I have many test suites in the form of files that are given to C program, I am using Perl to automate the input and get the coverage using `gcovr`.

Of course I've used  `system` command , and backtics in perl to call `gcc` and `gcovr`.

The first C program runs well, because the input to the program is read from arguments given.

But for the second C program, I got confused, because the program  only accepts input from keyboard or simply put "it is  using `scanf`".

So, how can we provide input to C programs that only accepts input from keyboard (`scanf`) through terminal linux or using perl with `system` command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` accepts input from `stdin`. You can redirect `stdin` to a file when you start your program and have the program get its input from that file.

Redirection is a feature of the OS, not a feature of a specific language.

Let's say you want to start your program and you know that this program will accept '10' 'y' and 'n' as input. All you have to do is to create a file with those lines in, by whatever way you can. Let's suppose that this file is named test_1.

You then start the program with `tested_program < test_1` and the program will use '10', 'y' and 'n' as its input.

Comment: I'm new in perl, would you mind putting some sample code in your answer please...

Comment: Fyi. The C program cannot modify or updated. I just to test it using perl.

Answer (score 0):

If using the Perl command `system` is not a strict requirement, you can consider using [Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html) instead. It is more advanced than system, and you can specify what to use for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. So you can write the input to your C program in a text file, create a handle to that file, and use Open3 to call your C program specifying that file handle as first argument.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code in your answer please?  I'm new in Perl. Maybe look for sample code would help me. :)

Comment: Fyi, the C program cannot updated or modify. I only can test it using Perl Script